# Java - issue with opening hibernate session over time

Tags: java, hibernate, synchronized

On a java application, I am getting the following error message around 12-24 hours of activity

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxxx.persistence.proxy.SessionFactoryProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(SessionFactoryProxy.java:322)
    at $Proxy11.openSession(Unknown Source)
    at com.xxxxxx.persistence.proxy.SessionFactoryProxy.openSession(SessionFactoryProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:425)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:322)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:176)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:210)
```

I compared this class with another application which I don t have this issue and the difference is `private` **synchronized** `SessionFactory getSessionFactory()`

I m not sure that would fix the issue or what if it s something else

```
private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    SessionFactory sf = sessionFactoryBuilder.getSessionFactory();

    if (!DBConnections.getHibernateSessionsProxyed().containsKey(DBConnections.getCustomer())) {
        Class sfInterface = SessionFactory.class;
        if (sf instanceof SessionFactoryImplementor) {
            sfInterface = SessionFactoryImplementor.class;
        }
        SessionFactory proxy = (SessionFactory) Proxy.newProxyInstance(sfInterface.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { sfInterface },
                new TransactionAwareInvocationHandler(sf));
        DBConnections.addSessionProxyed(proxy);
    }
    return DBConnections.getHibernateSessionProxyed();
}

public Session openSession() throws HibernateException {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession(); //line 221 from the error message
}

public static Map<String, SessionFactory> getHibernateSessionsProxyed() {
    if(hibernateSessionsProxyed == null) {
        hibernateSessionsProxyed = new HashMap<String, SessionFactory>();
    }
    return hibernateSessionsProxyed;
}

public static void addSessionProxyed(SessionFactory session) {
    if(hibernateSessionsProxyed == null) {
        hibernateSessionsProxyed = new HashMap<String, SessionFactory>();
    }
    hibernateSessionsProxyed.put(getCustomer(), session);
}

public TransactionAwareInvocationHandler(SessionFactory target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in your `DBConnections.getHibernateSessionProxyed()` method.  You should `synchronize` if you set the SessionFactory in a static storage.

Comment: Here the code the DBConnections.getHibernateSessionProxyed()
`public static Map<String, SessionFactory> getHibernateSessionsProxyed() {
  if(hibernateSessionsProxyed == null) {
   hibernateSessionsProxyed = new HashMap<String, SessionFactory>();
  }
  return hibernateSessionsProxyed;
 }`

Do you mean I should change this static to synchronize ?
Sorry i m not so familiar with that type of code

Comment: You need to post this to your question and also the code for `DBConnections.addSessionProxyed(proxy)` and `TransactionAwareInvocationHandler`

Comment: Sorry, I have added methods in the question

Comment: `hibernateSessionsProxyed` seems to be shared so you need to synchronize it properly whenever you add/remove entries.

Answer (score 0):

I changed private SessionFactory getSessionFactory() to private synchronized SessionFactory getSessionFactory() and the issue did nt come again after 4 weeks of activity